# Piranha- Custom Manager Area

Tags: piranha-cms

I created a custom page in the manager area and would like to add the text area for editing HTML content.  I can't seem to figure out how to reference the existing control.    Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an HTML-editor, follow these steps:

**1: Include the partial view that sets up the html-editor**

```
@Html.Partial("~/Areas/Manager/Views/Shared/Partial/TinyMCE.cshtml")
```

**2: Add the class editor to your textarea**

```
<textarea class="editor"></textarea>
```

That should do the trick.

Regards

/ Håkan

Comment: That was what I was needing.  Thank You Sir

Comment: The add image pop-up wont open on this page.  Works fine on the regular content pages.

Comment: You probably need the JavaScript for the media dialog, take a look at the post edit view here for example. https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/Piranha/blob/master/Core/Piranha/Areas/Manager/Views/Post/Edit.cshtml